# How to solve this system of differential equations where one differential is part of another?

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I need to solve this system of differential equations.

I tested it with removing `rk(3)` from the `rk(2)` equation and in that case I do get some solution. The code runs without error. However when I keep the `rk(3)` in the `rk(2)` equation I get a bunch of errors.

```
function rk = odes(t,y)

sigma1=sqrt(10e5);
sigma2=0.1;
sigma0=10e5;
m=1;k=2;vb=0.1;mis=0.15;mik=0.1;g=9.81;Fn=m*g;Fs=mis*Fn;Fc=mik*Fn;vs=0.001


rk(1)=y(2);
rk(2)=1/m*(sigma1*rk(3)+sigma0*y(3)+sigma2*vb-y(2)*(k+sigma2));
rk(3)=(vb-y(2))-((sigma0*(vb-y(2)))/(Fc+(Fs-Fc)*exp(-((vb-y(2)/vs)^2))));
rk=rk(:);

end
```

```
clc
close all
clear all


timerange=[0 20]
IC=[0.1;0;0.1]
[t,y]=ode45(@(t,y) odes(t,y),timerange,IC)

figure
plot(t,y(:,1));
```

[image: errors]

Comment: Just exchange the lines so that you compute `rk(3)` before `rk(2)`. It should not be necessary, but you can also insert a dummy declaration `rk(2)=0`, then `rk(3)=...`, then the proper assignment of `rk(2)`.

Comment: If you swap the two line rk(3)<-->rk(2) don't forget to adjust the `IC` vector (`IC= [0.1,0.1,0]`)

Comment: @obchardon : There is a difference between changing the order of computation leaving indices etc. the same, and changing the order of the components in the state vector, where indeed one would also have to adapt the IC to the changed order.

Comment: LoL I tried this and it didn't work, but now it did! I must have done something wrong. Thank you. However, there is still some strange things. For example, the vector t is equal to 0 for most of the time, only in the end (maybe the last 50 values or so) start raising to 20. Do you know why that is? https://i.imgur.com/iyDnDnd.png

Comment: That is due to the variable step size of the `ode45` solver. You can either change `timerange` to a time vector at which you want the solution, or interpolate `t` and `y` yourself after integration with a time vector of your choice.